# Hide a parent element if ID contains specific text string with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to hide a parent `<tr>` tag where a grandchild `<span>` tag has an ID with a specific string.

Let's say I want to check for the string "test123" in the ID, e.g.

```
<table>
  <tr id="this_is_a_test456">
    <td>
      <span>
        <span>

        <span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <<<--- THIS ROW SHOULD BE DELETED
    <td>
      <span>
        <span id="this_is_a_test123">

        <span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `<span>` within a `<tr>` by partial ID and if it exists, select the parent row and remove it

```js
let idPartial = 'test123'
let span = document.querySelector(`tr span[id*="${idPartial}"]`)
if (span) {
  span.closest('tr').remove()
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr id="this_is_a_test456">
    <td>
      <span>
        <span>My row stays<span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
        <span id="this_is_a_test123">My row goes<span>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See

- [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

---

The above finds the first element matching your condition (*"id attribute contains"*). If you wanted to do this for all matching `<span>` elements, use

```js
let idPartial = 'test123'
document.querySelectorAll(`tr span[id*="${idPartial}"]`).forEach(span => {
  span.closest('tr').remove()
})
```

As per [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), make sure your code runs *after* the document has loaded.

Comment: sorry but how would you implement the "matching all" code?

Comment: @DanielWilliams I'm not really sure what you mean. It's at the bottom of my answer

Comment: @DanielWilliams other than `idPartial` which I didn't include because it's already up the top, that's it. I've updated the second snippet to show the _"whole code"_